# Getting Paged Data Using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, pagination

I am implementing paging using LINQ, and i was thinking about the performance issues that i could encounter. Lets say i have a page size of 10 and i have 100 records in a table.
If i were to use the following

```
var myList = _dataContext.Person.Skip(PageNumber * PageSize).Take(10);
```

it will get me the data i want. now if i were to take this scenario, and apply it to 1,000,000 records. will this affect the performance? Would it be much more worth using an sql stored procedure, performance wise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stored procedures do not have any advantages over plain SQL text, which is generated for you by Linq provider.

*BTW* for your query something like following SQL will be generated

```
SELECT /* [t0] fields */
FROM (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY /* [t0] fields */
    FROM [Person] AS [t0]
    ) AS [t1]
WHERE [t1].[ROW_NUMBER] BETWEEN @p0 + 1 AND @p0 + @p1
ORDER BY [t1].[ROW_NUMBER]
```

And it will be executed only when you will use `myList` variable (e.g. call `ToList()`, `Count()`, enumerate it). Thus it does not matter how many persons you have in database (well, matter, but this is db part, not objects in memory), and you will not have performance boost from usage of stored procedure.

Answer (score 2):

This *won't* be returning all the rows from the database before it's skipping and taking. If you did a `ToList` after the `.Person`, then that would be very inefficient. What you have there should be fine